# I want to take a substring of a users email and direct them to a certain view controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Goal**: To take the substring of a Google users email

**Details**: I have just implemented Firebase Google Auth on my project and was wondering how to take a substring of a users email, and then direct them to a certain view Controller based on that.

If I have a user with an email bob@gmail.com I would send him to a different view controller than someone with an email sally@AOL.com.

I am using the firebase real-time database and storyboards to build out my app.

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: I'm looking for a method that will take in the current user's email, take a substring of it and then direct them to a pre-done viewController.

Comment: That's not specific. What code do you have? What have you tried? What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: You have now completely rewritten you question three times. Please stop.

Comment: Your right I got the answer I was looking for, sorry!

Comment: Just split the email string into it's components' `let components = emailString.split(separator: "@")` and then `let prefix = components.first` which will give you the name and `let suffix = components.last` which will give you the part you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
let str = "the email"

if str[str.count - 7] == "a"
{
    perform segueway? for aol.com
}
else if str[str.count - 9] == "g"
     {
         perform segueway? for gmail.com
}
else
{
     perform segueway? default?
}
```

and you will need to add this extension

```
extension String {

var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[0 ..< max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: min(length, max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
}

}
```

Comment: theres probably a more efficient way to do this tho

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for

Comment: make sure u flush out your logic, because if u put -9 = "g' first potentialy somebody with email gg.aol.com could get triggered at google